# Test the app that I send to AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

I send a new version of my iPad app to AppStore. The Apple will now validate it.

But, I want to have absolute certainty that NOTHING gone wrong. I have the Archived file and want to run it.

Ok, I can build a new program and run it in the device. But I want to test the exact file that I sent.

I tried to create a .ipa file but it give-me problem with "code signed". Run the file in simulator is a good idea. So, there are a easy way to run my new version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot install on our own device an app you build and is signed with your distribution certificate. Put another way, the build you submit to Apple cannot be directly installed by you on your device.

If you build any other way such that you can install that build on your device, it's the same code as you would otherwise be sending to Apple in a distribution build.

I have had the same desire, actually. I have an app with a conditional build setting based on whether it's a distribution build or not. For a distribution build, we have a *production* API URL, but for all other builds the URL is a development sandbox URL. So, I know how you feel! I wanted to be able to test the actual build sent to Apple to make sure it was hitting the correct production URL. I couldn't. I had to trust. :-)

Comment: You might want to have 2 Release builds, one with the sandbox URL and one with the production URL for final test before building the Distribution app.

Comment: Not a bad idea. The way I did it was to define a compiler macro in the Distribution build settings. In the code, if it's defined, I use the production URL, otherwise not. I like your idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using Xcode 4; details will be different if you're using Xcode 3.

Once you've created an application archive, you can select the archive in the Organizer and click the Share... button to e-mail it to yourself and/or your testers. Xcode will let you sign it with your developer key, so you can install it on your device. When you're satisfied with the app, you can then validate and submit the app to the app store, again from the Organizer window. You'll re-sign the app with your distribution key and the application will be uploaded to iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your project and your target Build settings are absolutely 100% identical between your final Release build and your Distribution build, except for code-signing.  Then do a clean build of both, one after the other, and QA the final Release build before submitting the Distribution archive.

After Apple approves the app, delete the app from one of your devices, and buy your app from the App store.  That's the only way to get an exact customer download with the full customer experience.  You'll get back 70% of the purchase price in a couple months; the other 30% is likely a very small part of your total development and testing cost.